# Explain the mongodb injection vulnerability presented by the checkKeys parameter

Tags: mongodb, code-injection

From the docs at https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html

> checkKeys {Boolean, default:true}, allows for disabling of document key checking (WARNING OPENS YOU UP TO INJECTION ATTACKS)

I cannot find any examples of this vulnerability being used.  Is it possible that I do some of my own sanitation to mitigate not using the built-in sanitation?  For example rejecting any objects which have keys that contain non-alphanumeric, non-period characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link refers to the documentation to the very old driver v1.4.9 which works with mongodb up to v3.0, retired in February 2018.

The `checkKeys` option there is for backward compatibility with pre v2.6 OP_INSERT wire protocol (support of v2.6 ended in October 2016).

It would be advisable to invest some effort in the upgrade rather than in some custom sanitation for ancient versions of the database.

Comment: Thanks. While I'm running 3.6, it's become clear that checkKeys is an undocumented flag for more current versions, so I'm going to go a different route than depend upon undocumented behavior.

Comment: The flag makes sense only in the legacy wire protocol which was deprecated in v2.0 release notes https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/upgrade-migration/upgrading/#collection-object to the degree of claiming no-support for pre v2.6 databases in https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/driver-compatibility-reference/#reference-compatibility-mongodb-node.  What makes you thinking `checkKeys` is still being used in the current versions of the driver?

Comment: Because I'm using it.  If I don't use it, I get exceptions when using keys with periods in them.  When I look in node_modules, I can see the mongodb package's package.json lists version 3.0.4.  `bson` still supports that flag, so I'd have to assume it gets passed on down.